# Getting div's attribute value in the different function (REACT)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

So basically, I have just started learning React and I wanted to create a simple add, which works as a shopping car. I am just wondering how to pass the price of an item to the function. I have done something like that below but it doesn't work and probably is not the best idea.

```
 <div className="item" onClick={this.addItem} itemPrice={12}><p class="itemDesc">Pizza</p></div>

   addItem() {
     let myItems = this.state.itemsOrdered;
     let myPrice = this.state.price;

     this.setState({
       itemsOrdered: myItems + 1,
       price: myPrice + this.itemPrice
     });
   }
```

I expect state price to increase by the value of clicked item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to fix the following errors:

> 1. Change the camel-case `itemPrice` to lowercase like this `itemprice` since React doesn't allow camel-case format for custom
>      attributes.
> 2. `class` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript. Replace: `<p class="itemDesc">` with `<p className="itemDesc">`.

---

So in order to access the clicked element's `itemprice` value and add it to your state property, you need to:

**First**, pass the clicked event object as a parameter to `addItem()` like this:

```
addItem(e) {

}
```

**Second**, assign the div you just clicked to a variable say, `clickObj` like this:

```
addItem(e) {
    let clickObj = e.currentTarget;
}
```

**Third**, retrieve the value of the `itemprice` attribute using the `getAttribute` method, parsed it to an integer and then assign it to another variable, say `newPrice`.

```
addItem(e) {
    let clickObj = e.currentTarget;
    let newPrice = parseInt(clickObj.getAttribute('itemprice'));
}
```

**Fourth**, Add the values of `this.state.price` and `newPrice` and then assign it to `this.state.price` like this:

```
addItem(e) {
    let clickObj = e.currentTarget;
    let newPrice = parseInt(clickObj.getAttribute('itemprice'));
    this.setState({
        price: this.state.price + newPrice
    });
}
```

---

Check the codepen below to see how I use the above approach to increment a state property's value on click:

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/andrewl64/pen/wRdvqP

Comment: Thanks very much for tips. That was really helpful! :)